# How to display or emulate a mobile preview of user website in my website

Tags: php, html, remote-server, web-testing

I tried iframe but it's not loading all of the website error: "refused to connect". Also i tried curl in php. But it's not getting the mobile preview.

```
<iframe id="preview-frame1" src="https://www.kd-brows.com/" style="height: 547px; width: 320px;"></iframe>
```

I checked this site "https://mobilemoxie.com/"
How I get like this remote emulator preview.

Answer (score 0):

One solution in this case you need to use proxied request that adds CORS headers

for example
[CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) is a NodeJS reverse proxy which adds CORS headers to the proxied request.

After that you include the proxied link to your iframe .

There are other solutions Like using curl to get page sources.

Comment: I tried also curl but didn't work to load a view of mobile site.